Difference of Measurable Sets using Caratheodory’s Criterion
Say we have an outer measure $\mu^*$ on a set $X$, and we define a subset $M\subset X$ to be measurable if and only if for every subset $A\subset X$,
$$
\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A\cap M)+\mu^*(A\cap M^c)\, .
$$
I am having trouble proving that if $M$ and $N$ and measurable then $M\setminus N$ is also measurable. While I'm following an analysis book by Charles Pugh for this approach to measure theory, he unfortunately "proves" this statement with a picture, which for me is not a proof. If anyone has a different reference which uses this notion of measurability or a hint at a proof it would be much appreciated.

Typically, we prove that: 1. If $M$ is measurable, then $M^c$ is measurable (it is trivial from the definition); 2. If $M$ and $N$ are measurable, then $M \cup N$ is measurable.  Then, since $M \setminus N=M \cap N^c= (M^c \cup N)^c$, it is immediate that, if $M$ and $N$ are measurable, then  $M \setminus N$.  So, you only need to prove 2.  It is a standard proof that you can find in almost any book presenting Measure Theory.

I have posted a complete answer following the line of my comment above. Let me know if you have any questions regarding the answer.


Let  $\mu^*$  be an outer measure on $X$ (that is $\mu^*$ is defined on $\mathcal{P}(X)$). Then:
$1$. if $M$ is measurable, the $M^c$ is measurable;
$2$. if $M$ and $N$ are measurable, then $M \cup N$ is measurable;
$3$. if $M$ and $N$ are measurable, then $M \setminus N$ is measurable

Proof:
Item $1$: It is trivial from the definition of (Caratheodory’s) measurability.
Item $2$: Given any $A \subseteq X$, since $M$ is measurable, we have
$$ \mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A\cap M)+\mu^*(A\cap M^c) $$
Sice $N$ is measurable, we have
$$\mu^*(A\cap M) = \mu^*(A\cap M \cap N) + \mu^*(A\cap M \cap N^c)$$
and
$$\mu^*(A\cap M^c) = \mu^*(A\cap M^c \cap N) + \mu^*(A\cap M^c \cap N^c)$$
combining the three equalities, we have
\begin{align*} \mu^*(A) = &\mu^*(A\cap M \cap N) + \mu^*(A\cap M \cap N^c) + \\ &+\mu^*(A\cap M^c \cap N) + \mu^*(A\cap M^c \cap N^c) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Now, note that $M \cup N = (M \cap N) \cup (M \cap N^c) \cup (M^c \cap N)$. So, we have
\begin{align*}
\mu^*&(A) \leqslant \mu^*(A \cap (M \cup N)) + \mu^*(A\cap (M \cup N)^c) = \\
& =\mu^*(A \cap ((M \cap N) \cup (M \cap N^c) \cup (M^c \cap N))) + \mu^*(A\cap (M^c \cap N^c)) = \\
& =\mu^*((A \cap M \cap N) \cup (A \cap M \cap N^c) \cup (A \cap M^c \cap N)) + \mu^*(A\cap M^c \cap N^c) \leqslant \\
& \leqslant  \mu^*(A\cap M \cap N) + \mu^*(A\cap M \cap N^c) + \mu^*(A\cap M^c \cap N) + \mu^*(A\cap M^c \cap N^c) = \\
& = \mu^*(A)
\end{align*}
where the inequelities come from the sub-additivity of $\mu^*$ and the last equality comes from ($1$).
So we have proved that $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A \cap (M \cup N)) + \mu^*(A\cap (M \cup N)^c)$. So, $M \cup N$ is measurable.
Item $3$: Since $M$ is measurable, by item $1$ we know that $M^c$ is measurable. Since $N$ is measurable, by item $2$ we know that $M^c \cup N$ is measurable. Using again item $1$, we have that $(M^c \cup N)^c$ is measurable. But, $M \setminus N = M \cap N^c = (M^c \cup N)^c$, So, $M \setminus N$ is measurable.
